# Software like Google Fonts for local fonts

Tags: fonts, software-recommendation, font-management

I would like a tool that let me easily experiment with the fonts I have on my computer.

Ideally it would be a local Google Fonts-like system, letting me type and filter font by types or by name to easily visualize the same text over different fonts. I am on a Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you ask for is called a *font manager* software. There are many such software, depending on how much money your willing to spend. Unfortunately the free ones on mac are a bit scarce, windows on the other hand has many good free ones. You can easily find scores of options by typing [font manager](https://www.google.com/search?q=font+manager&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) into google. There are many features to choose form including font syncing license management and team workflow tools.

Comment: I was missing the name, which doesn't help to Google, thanks for that!