# How can I compare specific copy across all installed fonts?

Tags: fonts, typography, workflow

When I chose a font for a project, I always spend way too much time. 
I'd like to type the copy in a program, and it would be displayed in each font installed on my computer so I can compare which font is the best (in terms of kerning, etc). [This is a work-intensive alternative](https://alvinalexander.com/mac-os-x/mac-osx-free-font-tester-comparison-tool) - I don't have time to do this, and my installed fonts change often.

I remember I used to be able to do that with free apps a long time ago under **Mac OS 9** (*Font Image Library*, *Font Gander*, etc), and commercial font websites let you type custom text, but I cannot find any apps that do it for installed fonts under Mac OS X.

Comment: There are really a few font management apps for either OS - FontXplorer, Suitcase, FontAgentPro.. just search for "font manger" you can view installed or uninstalled fonts easily.  I voted to close this because A) it's not *really* graphic design based (maybe SuperUser.com) and B) which is "best" is really just opinion. Also, [see here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77345/software-like-google-fonts-for-local-fonts).

Comment: I disagree with Ⓐ and Ⓑ but not with Ⓒ! (See what I did there?) Fonts are absolutely designs, whether they represent letters, dingbats, hieroglyphs... and 100% of designers chose fonts regularly in their workflow. And I'm not asking what's "best" - just what it's called and whether it exists. BUT you're right, this question was asked, I just didn't see it.

Comment: Viewing fonts on an OS is an OS question.. *not* a design question. But, that's merely my opinion. Fr what it's worth, I've used FontAgent Pro for a decade on the Mac without any complaints.

Comment: Looks like my own older choices for this task have been comfortably eclipsed - I'd say from what I've just been seeing that Setapp's TypeFace 2 is really a fluent and fluid solution.

Comment: @GerardFalla but be sure to look at the instructions for auto-activation in InDesign.... ugh :) I too thought it looked nice (although I have no interest right now in replacing FontAgent). But then, I saw there were "special" options for InDesign. I wonder how it fairs with Illustrator.

Comment: @Scott: Comparing fonts is something that designers do more than other people. Hence designers tend to have the most experience about how to best do this. Hence it is a good question for designers, i.e., this community. Please see [this Meta discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/19174).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it should be then marked as duplicate of the one Scott linked to (I retracted my close vote so I can't vote again) https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/77345/software-like-google-fonts-for-local-fonts

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Font Preview for several years, and quite like it - allows multi font comparative previews of custom sample text quite easily - here's a screengrab from off my main graphics & 3D modeling machine:

[image]

Cheap, fast, lower system overhead than native Font Book, and easy to use.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free version of [FontBase](https://fontba.se), I've tried it on Windows and it works great, but I never tried on Mac.